# Generic Expression Filter

Tags: c#, linq, generics, expression

Hi I am hoping someone might be able to provide a little guidance with the following:

I am trying to create a Generic Expression Filter that uses reflection and can receive a set of rules and create a valid expression for restricting the data returned from a Datasource.

The problem I am having is trying to understand how to write an expression to handle the following scenario.

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<TagTypes> TagTypes { get; set; }
}

public class TagTypes
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Tags> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tags
{
    public string TagName { get; set; }
}
```

The data essentially would look like

```
var itemList = new List<Item>
            {
                new Item
                {
                Name = "xyz",
                TagTypes = new List<TagTypes>
                    {
                        new TagTypes
                        {
                            Name = "Genre",
                            Tags = new List<Tags>
                                {
                                new Tags
                                    {
                                        TagName = "tag1"
                                    },
                                new Tags
                                    {
                                        TagName = "tag2"
                                    }        
                                }
                        }
                    }
               }

            };
```

I would like to write an expression that returns me all the items that match the filter of 'Genre' --> 'tag1'

I can do this using the following:

```
var filtered = from item in itemList
from tagType in item.TagTypes
   where tagType.Name == "Genre"
      from tag in tagType.Tags
      where tag.TagName == "tag1"
select item
```

And have a basic working version that works fine for properties on the Item class however I can't figure out how to do the SelectMany on TagTypes and below.

The Basic level is just the following

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "itemList");
var property = GetPropertyInfo<T>({Propertyname});
var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
Expression.Equal(propertyAccess, Expression.Constant({Value}));
```

---

**Edit**

The data is stored in a NoSQL database, the filter is dynamic and can change and be added to.

The reason for creating a Genric Filter with reflection is to accommodate different filters without having to know what they are upfront. Users will be able to request data using a filter id, this will then select the data based on the filter in the request.

Comment: Why do you need to create an expression? Just use variables for Name and TagName.

Comment: @adrianm the need to create an expression comes from wanting to pass the query down to the NoSQL Linq provider. The DB potentially has 60K+ records and as I don't know exactly what property the user will filter on it seems like the most sensible solution

Comment: @adrianm the above structure is a cut down version of the actual objects

Comment: @SCB what will be the user input to create a Filter, or if they are "predefined" how will they be builded ? Something like type of items to be returned, and a kind of tuple `property to filter-value(s) of the proeprty` ?

Comment: SelectMany is just a method call in an expression which is probably not what you want. I assume your provider actually wants an IQueryable rather than an expression.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus the filters are created in an external system, and saved in the NoSQL DB. The system uses the filters to create a list of items to return

Comment: @adrianm The use of SelectMany allows the array to be flattened. This allows us to target individual Items within the array

Comment: I know what SelectMany does. What I am saying is that from an expression point of view it is just a method call. Unless your linq provider got its own SelectMany method you need to use the one with an IQueryable argument. i.e. You need to construct an IQueryable that you can call SelectMany on and pass your built expression as argument.

Comment: @adrianm, OK so if my list for example was an IQueryable I could pass that into an Expression.Call and use the SelectMany that way?

Comment: I think you misunderstand how IQueryable works. Your linq provider supplies the IQueryable. You only need to generate the select/where expressions. var q = MyProviderIQueryable.SelectMany(myselectexpression).Where(myfilterexpression)...

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be over complicating this.

You can just write an `Expression<Func<Item>>` or `Expression<Func<List<Item>>` and select the `Body` property.

e.g.

```
 Expression<Func<List<Item>> createListOfItems = () => new List<Item>
        {
            new Item
            {
            Name = "xyz",
            TagTypes = new List<TagTypes>
                {
                    new TagTypes
                    {
                        Name = "Genre",
                        Tags = new List<Tags>
                            {
                            new Tags
                                {
                                    TagName = "tag1"
                                },
                            new Tags
                                {
                                    TagName = "tag2"
                                }        
                            }
                    }
                }
           }

        };
```

Comment: Im not 100% sure I explained myself properly. As per my edit the filter will drive what data is retrieved from a no SQL database I will not know which properties or values the user has requested until runtime.

Comment: @SCB, then we'd need to see the schema for your object model